# Why my website redirects to an other url?

Tags: url, redirect, mobile, virus

When I open my website in mobile, it redirect to an other url. I check my website from here http://vms.drweb.com/online/?lng=en it gives me this result 
[image]

How can I fix this issue ?
My website is in magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download fresh .htaccess file of magento and replace it with old.